# Function arguments referring to the same variable

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Calling `f(a,a)` in the following code is undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int &m, int &n) {
  m++;
  n++;
  return m + n;
}


int main() {
  int a = 1;
  int b = f(a, a);
}
```

Comment: No. Do you have any reason to thing it would be? If so, it might improve the question if you add that information.

Comment: No that is not undefined behavior. Although strange, that is completely valid.

Comment: But `return ++m + ++n;` would be.

Comment: Should 'strict aliasing' figure in the discussion?

Comment: Are you sure @Jarod42? Why would that be undefined?

Comment: @iwolf Two modifications of the same thing with no intervening sequence point?

Comment: @Jarod42 good spot, I didn't consider that before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you clarify you concerns about aliasing? It is not clear to me how the compiler can assume `n` and `m` do not alias but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I'm not sufficiently sure to know whether aliasing is an issue.  That's why I asked a question, rather than trying to claim it should be part of the discussion.  I've not studied strict aliasing w.r.t C++, so I can't usefully opine.  It is 100% possible that it is a complete red herring, in which case, these comments about it should probably be removed - or a comment stating that aliasing is not an issue could be added to help future readers.

Comment: Like @juanchopanza I am also curious why you concerned this was undefined behavior, was it a particular SO question on undefined behavior?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler strict aliasing is not an issue here; `int` can be aliased as `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with respect to modifying `m` and `n` since the modifications of both variables are sequenced. The modification of `m` will happen before the modification of `n` since they are both full expressions and all side effects of a full expression are sequenced before the side effects of the next full expression.

The relevant section of the [draft C++ standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) is section `1.9` *Program execution* which says:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a
>   full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.8.

and:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either
>   another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined

on the other hand the following:

```
m++ + n++ ;
```

is undefined behavior since the the order of evaluation of each sub expression is indeterminately sequence with respect to each other.

Jonathan brings up the issue of [strict aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) but I don't see how the compiler can assume that `n` and `m` are not aliasing each other and my experiments on [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) does not indicate any unexpected aliasing assumptions.

Note, a *full expression* is:

> [...]an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression[...]

Usually the `;` denotes the end of a *full expression*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no undefined behavior here. `a` will end up being `3` and `b` will be `6`, consistently.